# Django - Force a user to reset initial password

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am implementing a functionality where a user is forced to change a password (i.e. if the admin creates an initial password, the user is required to change it on the next login). I am using the Django Contrib Auth package.

For this, I have a extended the user profile by a boolean parameter `force_password_change`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  force_password_change = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

In my view, I am extending the standard `LoginView`:

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
  def form_valid(self, form):
      # form is valid (= correct password), now check if user requires to set own password
      if form.get_user().profile.force_password_change:
          return HttpResponseRedirect('password_change')
      else:
          auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
          return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

The system renders a 404 page not found error after I click the `login` button: `The current path, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.`

I noticed that when I add `auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())` just before the `HttpResponseRedirect('password_change')` it works fine. But this also means that the user is (incorrectly) authenticated.

`urls.py`:

```
path('', myapp.MyLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('password_change/', myapp.MyPasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
```

Why is this the case and why is the 404 error refering to `accounts/login/`?

Comment: I am facing same issue like your's. Could you please share code for complete password reset if possible?.

Comment: @DevKing Hi, how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) for resolving the url name:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # form is valid (= correct password), now check if user requires to set own password
        if form.get_user().profile.force_password_change:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('password_change'))
        else:
            auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: can you change the url names for your urls.py, because it may contradict with https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py (not sure though)

Comment: Same issue... it works fine when adding ```auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())```. When I don't, it doesn't work...

Comment: In password change view, do you have any kind of restrictions like login required?

Comment: Nope, I tested that as well.

Comment: Can you please look into this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Answer (score -1):

Use [User.set_unusable_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password), then assuming your password change view is called 'change-password':

Add this to your login view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import revese

if not user.has_usable_password():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('change-password')
```

Comment: not sure where this should go and how it would solve the redirect issue? Can you elaborate further?

Comment: How can a user login with set_unusable_password() called already ?